# How can I edit an action strip while seeing the global NLA animation playing?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

I'm playing with the NLA editor so I can use action strips, but I think I don't understand how it works.

From what I understand, I can see the NLA (global) animation only if there is no action opened in the *Action Editor*.

I can edit an Action Strip by right-clicking it then *Start Editing Stashed Action* from within the NLA.  It is now open in the action editor.  But I don't see anymore the global animation of the NLA so it's difficult to work correctly.

Is there a way to edit an Action Strip while the global animation plays ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs the answer, it's possible now with menu **Edit -> Start Tweaking Strip Actions (Full Stack)**

And it's default mode in Blender 4.0. Before 4.0 the default is **Start Editing Stashed Action**, which edits the action in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

If you select the strip in the *NLA* and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the action will open in the *Dope Sheet* and the other objects will continue to be animated.

The only problem is that the action you want to edit will stick to the beginning of the timeline, or at the frame where it is supposed to begin in the *Dope Sheet* as an action, not at the frame where the strip is placed in the *NLA*.

To make it begin at the same frame as in the *NLA*, enable the track pinning option:

[image]

Comment: when I press tab, it seems to isolate my action - I can't see the "sum" of the NLA...

Comment: that's weird, it works fine here, I hope someone will understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

I received this answer from @GuitlyGhost [on blender.chat](https://blender.chat/channel/animation?msg=t6eTg8oJr8A5Rtjhg) :

> strips have blend modes. To prevent the top most action track (orange) from completely overriding your lower strips, change its blend mode to Combine instead of Replace.

> If you want to edit a strip while still viewing the complete NLA result, **that's not supported yet** and currently in development